# как узнать на какую кнопку нажали?

Tags: php, html, form

цыклом генерируються блоки с групами, и в каждом форма с кнопкой, в которой name ="" тоже генерируеться.. как узнать на какую именно кнопку нажал пользователь?? есть идеи??

```
$iii = 0;
while ($iii < count($rand_t)) {
$num_list = $iii + 1;
$chance = round(100 / ${row_ready_.$iii}['members_t'], 2); 
$won = round(${row_ready_.$iii}['members_t'] * 0.8);
echo $won;
echo "<form class=\" form-inline\" action = \"\" method=\"post\" style=\"max-width: 500px; margin: auto; text-align: center; background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9); padding: 10pt; border-radius: 15pt; \">
    <label>№$num_list | </label>
    <label></label>
    <label>members - </label>
    <p class=\"form-control\" style=\"margin: 0 0 0; min-width: 40pt\">".${row_ready_.$iii}['members_is']."/".${row_ready_.$iii}['members_t']."</p>
    <label>chance - </label>
    <p class=\"form-control\" style=\"margin: 0 0 0; min-width: 55pt\">".$chance."%</p>

    <label></label>
    <label>prize: <b><span style=\"border: 1pt solid #4b4b4b;font-size: 8pt;background: #120e0e;border-radius: 2pt; color: #dadada\"><span style=\"color: #ffd700\">&nbsp;●</span> ".$won." </b></span> &nbsp; </p></label>
    <button class=\"btn btn-success form-control\" name =\" ".${row_ready_.$iii}['name_t']." \">join</button>
    </form>
</div>
";
$iii++;
}
```

Comment: Зачем генерировать name, когда можно генерировать value?

Comment: @andreymal можно подробней? а то я только начал учить)